# 6 high severity vulnerabilities while installing react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-router, react-router-dom

I am a beginner in react and while installing react router i faced this issue, I dont know what to do now i could really use some suggestions.

Thank You in advance!!

Following is the error:

```
PS C:\Users\nagar\OneDrive\Documents\VS Code\React JS\textutils> npm install react-router-dom  

added 3 packages, and audited 1448 packages in 4s

194 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:     
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS C:\Users\nagar\OneDrive\Documents\VS Code\React JS\textutils>ls>
```

[image]

Comment: It's quite common, and if you let npm solve the issues you might get even more packages which have issues. Trying to change things without exact knowledge ends up that all your packages have wrong versions.
Beside that the question is not related to specific code and not related to StackOverflow but more to https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Note also that it's the responsibility of the developers of the packages that react-router relies on to get those vulnerabilities fixed. If you go to their github issues page you may find that the problem has already been logged/resolved ready for the next release. If not you could always add a new issue.